# Kotlin/Android: Finding all Views of type T recursively

Tags: android, recursion, kotlin, stack, extension-function

So I have this extension function for `ViewGroup` :

```
inline fun <reified T : View> ViewGroup.allViewsOfType(action: (T) -> Unit) 
{
    val views = Stack<View>()

    afterMeasured {
        views.addAll((0 until childCount).map(this::getChildAt))
    }

    while (!views.isEmpty()) {
        views.pop().let {
            if (it is T) action(it)
            if (it is ViewGroup) {
                afterMeasured {
                    views.addAll((0 until childCount).map(this::getChildAt))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
tabs.allViewsOfType<Button> { Log.i("Dale", it.text.toString()) }
```

But somehow it doesn't work. Anything that I'm doing wrong?

Btw, `tabs` is a `LinearLayout` that contains three `Button`s in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use `afterMeasure` in the particular case?

1. I just removed `afterMeasure`:

   ```
   inline fun <reified T : View> ViewGroup.allViewsOfType(action: (T) -> Unit) {
       val views = Stack<View>()

       views.addAll((0 until childCount).map(this::getChildAt))

       while (!views.isEmpty()) {
           views.pop().let {
               if (it is T) action(it)
               if (it is ViewGroup) {
                   views.addAll((0 until childCount).map(this::getChildAt))
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Replaced `Log.i()` logger with simple Kotlin's `println()`:

   ```
   tabs.allViewsOfType<Button> {
       println("Dale: ${it.text}")
   }
   ```
3. And now your function works just fine:

   ```
   I/System.out: Dale: Button 4
                 Dale: Button 3
                 Dale: Button 2
                 Dale: Button 1
   ```